# Seeming contradiction when electrostatics question solved with conservation of angular momentum vs conservation of energy

Tags: electrostatics, angular-momentum, energy-conservation

I am unsure if the title of the question is appropriate, but kindly excuse me for that.
And I am also not sure if this would be a homework help problem, if it is, I apologise in advance.
While solving some problems on electrostatics with my friend, we came across a question where we solved it with two approaches and got very different answers.

I attached a picture of the question below.[image: the problem from Understanding Physics by DC Pandey]

The question basically provided a charge configuration where a point charge is projected with an initial velocity, and we are asked the separation between the charges when the velocity of the projected particle is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ times the projected velocity

So, my friend and I had different approaches to solving this question, which I will detail below:

**I) My Approach:**

I started by considering the energy of the projected charge during its journey. Initially the charge is at a separation R and has a velocity V with mass M.
Thus I reasoned that total mechanical energy, initially, $E_i = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{Q(2q)}{R} + \frac{1}{2} MV^2$
And final mechanical energy when velocity is $\frac{1}{\sqrt3} V$ would be
$E_f = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{Q(2q)}{r} + \frac{1}{2} M(\frac{V}{\sqrt3})^2$
where $r$ is the separation between the charges at such a velocity.

Now, since the force being considered here is ONLY electrostatic force which is conservative, I used conservation of energy to conclude that $E_i = E_f$

Upon some rearrangement and simplification, to isolate $r$, I got

$r = \frac{R}{1+\frac{4\pi\epsilon_0 MV ^2 R}{qQ}}$
Which shows that the final separation, $r$ is dependent on the magnitudes of M, V, R, q and Q.
Now, for my friend's approach.

**II) My Friend's Approach:**

She considered the angular momentum of the projected charge. Since the electrostatic force acts along the line joining the centers of the charges, the net torque of $2q$ about the charge $Q$  would be 0, thus angular momentum is conserved. And she also said that at minimum separation, the velocity of approach would be perpendicular the the line joining the centers of both charges (which I frankly did not understand clearly, but I accepted what she said for the moment) and that would let us use conservation of angular momentum as follows.
Initial angular momentum = $\vec r \times \vec p = MVR sin(30^{\circ}) = \frac{MVR}{2}$

Final angular momentum =  $\vec r \times \vec p = M\frac{V}{\sqrt 3}r sin(90^{\circ}) = \frac{MVr}{\sqrt 3}$
Where $r$ is the least separation at the given velocity

Now using conservation of angular momentum, she said,
$\frac{MVR}{2} = \frac{MVr}{\sqrt 3}$
and concluded that $r = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}R$

which is infact the correct answer according the answer at the back of the book.
But her answer shows that the value of $r$ is **independent** of M, V, q and Q and simply depends on their initial separation. Which is completely different from what I got.

I think I am going wrong somewhere, and both of us don't know why my solution was incorrect. And FYI, we are high school students right now(seniors).

If someone can explain me why such a contradiction is arising, it would really help me out. Maybe I have mislearnt a concept, or applied it incorrectly, I am not sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: This question is really poorly written - the phrasing is really overcomplicated. And why wouldnt the second charge just be $q$. Without loss of generality redefine $q=2q$ right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the question is wrong. It's "overconstrained" meaning that too many quantities were defined by the question - such that some of them contradict each other if you think $Q$, $2q$, $V$, and $R$ are all free parameters that could take any value. In the end, both you and your friend are correct. You should set your answers equal to eachother and you get some condition on what values of $Q$, $2q$, $V$, and $R$ are possible.

To prove this, I should show that I can calculate one of the quantities given in the question by not assuming it to be true. I think the way I'd most like to do this would be to assume that the $V_f=V/\sqrt{3}$ thing isn't true. So I'll calculate the velocity at closest approach.

The initial angular momentum is $mVR\sin\theta$, the final is $mV_fr_f$. The initial energy is
$$
E_I=k\frac{Q(2q)}{R}+\frac{1}{2}mV^2
$$
The final is
$$
E_F=k\frac{Q(2q)}{r_f}+\frac{1}{2}mv_f^2
$$
Starting from the angular momentum conservation I get
$$
V_f=VR\sin(\theta)/r_f
$$
So I plug this into the energy relation and get the co
condition:
$$
k\frac{Q(2q)}{R}+\frac{1}{2}mV^2=k\frac{Q(2q)}{r_f}+\frac{1}{2}m(VR\sin(\theta)/r_f)^2
$$
Then I could solve for $r_f$ as a quadratic equation, and find $V_f$. I'm not feeling like doing that - suffice to say that I *could* solve for $v_f$, which is a big problem given that the question asker thought they could tell you $v_f=V/\sqrt{3}$.

Now to be a bit rude - this question is really poorly written and hard to read, and it's wrong. I would be careful trusting anything this book says.

Comment: That makes so much sense. Thank you very much for taking the time out to explain this to me. I had never really considered the possibility that this question could be wrong, as it is from one of the most popular Indian textbooks for high school students of physics, and to be very honest, I had never even tried to see if physics questions were over/underconstrained. That actually gave me a lot of insight, and I will keep this in mind.         Thanks a lot once again, your explanation was of great help!!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't check your algebra, but essentially there is no contradiction. Both energy and angular momentum are conserved. If you were to solve the full trajectory equation, you would find that the $qQ$ value would need to be such that your energy equation would give the same $r$ as the angular momentum equation in order for the closest approach velocity to be the one given.

Comment: Yes, I have come to realise that now, after reading the other explanation. Thank you very much for your answer, it is actually a great relief that I have not messed up, because I was afraid that my concepts weren't good because I was not getting the same answer. Thank you very much